# Is there not enough shim on my suspension pivot?

Tags: maintenance, mountain-bike, full-suspension, axle

I bought month ago new full suspension bike "*[Kellys Beast 2013](http://www.kellysbike.com/int/bikes-2013/mountain/fullsuspension/beast)*". When I maintained it, I noticed that there seems to be a shim missing on one rear pivot:
[image]

The most interesting that it is symmetrical and on the other side of the wheel is also an empty space for a shim. So I am confused.

Is there really a missing shim?

**NOTE:** The bike stands head over heels, so it's view from below.

Comment: If it's the same on both sides, either it is intended or someone at the manufacturer is really bad at assembling things. I would guess the former is correct but have nothing to proof it right.

Comment: Thanks, as for me I'm more inclined to think that mechanic lost 2 shims. The empty space seems exactly for shim size.

Comment: Most likely that bike was mounting in my country, not at the manufacturer plant, so mechanic can something missed

Comment: How about contacting the manufacturer?

Comment: @JamesMorris I wrote them mail, but had recived no response yet.

Comment: Just realized there was an image in the post that was blocked by a plugin. What is shown in the picture looks to me like its missing one half of a bushing - as canadmos mentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very possible that during assembly, the pieces were missed.

Try to see if you can shift the seat-stay or chain-stay sideways on the pivot. If you can, you definitely need to find another bushing to fit in there.

If there is sideways play in that pivot, it will wear out prematurely. You'll also get all sorts of dirt and debris stuck in there, which will also wear out the pivot much quicker than if it were covered with a bushing.

Another thing you could do is go to a brick and mortar store that sells the same brand of bike and see if the bikes in the store are also missing them.

Comment: A little bit of info about bushings here: http://www.pinkbike.com/news/To-The-Point-Bushings-2013.html